# Comparaison of two list in python

Tags: python, list

i have a string like this :

```
my_string = "apple,orange,kiwi,mange"
```

wich i split to make this list:

```
my_list_string = my_string.split(',')
```

and i have a second list :

```
my_list = ["kiwi", "apple", "mange", "orange"]
```

in my comparaison of those two list i want to return true if all elements in `my_list` are in the String `my_string`, so i did it like this :

```
my_list_string = my_string.split(',')
my_list = ["kiwi", "apple", "mange", "orange"]
if len(my_list_string) == len (set(my_list) & set(my_list_string)):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

is there an other way (the easiest, most elegant and the most efficient one) to make this comparaison ?

Comment: Does http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the most efficient way, since `set`s have O(1) amortized lookup

```
>>> my_string = "apple,orange,kiwi,mange"
>>> my_list = ["kiwi", "apple", "mange", "orange"]
>>> set(my_list).issubset(my_string.split(','))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option to check if there is any difference between two sets (using [symmetric_difference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)):

```
my_string = "apple,orange,kiwi,mange"
my_list_string = my_string.split(',')
my_list = ["kiwi", "apple", "mange", "orange"]

if set(my_list_string) ^ set(my_list):
    return False
else:
    return True
```